# How to search data through indices in pandas Series without loops

Tags: python, pandas

I need to write a function that takes 3 arguments (series, firstname, lastname). Series is pd.Series with grades where indices are names of students. The function should output the grade of the given student.

For example: `function((pd.Series([A, B], index = ['Ann Smith', 'John Doe]), 'John', 'Doe']`. And the output should be 'B'.

With a known name that would be just slicing, like `Series['John Doe] ---> 'B'`

But how to make this within a function? Loops and if's are forbidden.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
s = pd.Series(['A', 'B'], index = ['Ann Smith', 'John Doe'])

def get_grade(series, first_name, last_name):
    name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
    return series[name]

get_grade(s, 'John', 'Doe')
```

Comment: Yes, thanks! Just wrote kinda similar and it worked (name = 'firstname' +' ' + 'lastname')